# Scrapy: scraping website where targeted items are populated using document.write

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a website where targeted items are populated using `document.write` method. How can I get full browser html rendered version of the website in the **Scrapy**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, as scrapy will not execute the JavaScript code.

What you can do:

- Rely on a **headless browser** like Selenium, which will execute the JavaScript. Afterwards, use XPath (or simple DOM access) like before to query the web page *after* executing the page.
- Understand where the contents come from, and **load and parse the source directly** instead. Chrome Dev Tools / Firebug might help you with that, have a look at the "Network" panel that shows fetched data.

  Especially look for JSON, sometimes also XML.